# Java Spring Batch StoredProcedureItemReader Implementation (SYSBASE IQ)

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am implementing spring batch `StoredProcedureItemReader` resultset type. It's working fine when I'm calling procedure through `JdbcTemplate`, but when I use `StoredProcedureItemReader` as reader it's giving me an error. I'm using **SYBASE IQ as DB**, Stored Procedure return type is resultset.

Code Snippet: my configuration for `StoredProcedureItemReader` Spring Batch etl. method have one job parameter which I'm passing as parameter to procedure (SYBASE IQ DB). The return type of Stored procedure is resultset one select statement with multiple row.

```java
@Bean(destroyMethod="")
@StepScope
public StoredProcedureItemReader<TransactionReportingBean>  dataExtractReader(
    @Value("#{jobParameters[clientName]}") String clientName) throws Exception {

    StoredProcedureItemReader<TransactionReportingBean> 
    storedProcedureItemReader = new StoredProcedureItemReader<>();    
    storedProcedureItemReader.setDataSource(sybaseIqSource);

    storedProcedureItemReader.setProcedureName("getResult"); /**getClientPositionIBORData**/
    SqlParameter[] parameters = {new SqlParameter("ClientName", Types.VARCHAR)};
    storedProcedureItemReader.setParameters(parameters);

    storedProcedureItemReader.setPreparedStatementSetter(new PreparedStatementSetter() {
        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement arg0) throws SQLException {
            arg0.setString(1,clientName);
         }
        });

    storedProcedureItemReader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<TransactionReportingBean>(TransactionReportingBean.class));
    storedProcedureItemReader.afterPropertiesSet();

    storedProcedureItemReader.setVerifyCursorPosition(false);
    storedProcedureItemReader.close();
    return storedProcedureItemReader;
}
```

**error:**

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException:
>   Executing stored procedure; SQL [{call getResult(?)}JZ0SB: Parameter
>   index out of range: 0.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException:
>   JZ0SB: Parameter index out of range: 0.
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:110)
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
>         at org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader.openCursor(StoredProcedureItemReader.java:228)
>         at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.doOpen(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:426)
>         at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:146)
>         ... 33 more
>       Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: JZ0SB: Parameter index out of range: 0.
>         at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseError(Unknown Source)
>         at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ParamManager.int(Unknown Source)
>         at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ParamManager.doGetOutValueAt(Unknown Source)
>         at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ParamManager.doGetOutObjectAt(Unknown Source)
>         at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ParamManager.getOutObjectAt(Unknown Source)
>         at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybCallableStatement.getObject(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingCallableStatement.getObject(DelegatingCallableStatement.java:144)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingCallableStatement.getObject(DelegatingCallableStatement.java:144)
>         at org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader.openCursor(StoredProcedureItemReader.java:221)
>         ... 35 more
>       2018-10-15 16:57:25 - main        - ERROR [AbstractStep:274]: Exception while closing step execution resources in step Step in job
>   dataExtractorStepJob
>       org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Error while closing item reader

Comment: Can you please share the code that works properly with the jdbcTemplate for comparison?

Comment: Why are you calling `close` and `afterPropertiesSet`? Don't do that.

Comment: after remove still it's not working

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to remove `storedProcedureItemReader.close()`, Spring Batch will close the reader automatically at the end of the result set.

According to the stacktrace, you would probably need to set the `refCursorPosition` to 1:

```
storedProcedureItemReader.setRefCursorPosition(1);
```

Hope this helps.